# App crash if enabled proguard

Tags: java, android-studio, crash

If enable proguard in my application with this code:

```
release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Application crash only if published in Play Store when try to run in Debug or Normal mode from Android Studio applcation not crash.

Error when crash:

```
Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.aj.a()' on a null object reference
```

I m using latest version for support.v7:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'      
}
```

Before today all working fine =(

Dexter say:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

and it work but why after any update of android studio i have always problem?? Why Android Studio after latest version of today proguard cancel widget?

Comment: Thank you man. This is why I started hating Google/Android etc. You go by the book. You do everything they want. Nothing works. Why does proguard remove a library that is imported and referenced, declared and used? And then you find out only when testing the signed apk from playstore, when everyone has it on the phone already. Now I'll have to test the signed, shrinked apk before uploading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe proguard removes this class, you can disable proguard to avoid this error if you want keep it you will have to change proguard settings

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but why any update of Android Studio i have 10000 problems?? Before update of today Android Studio not delete this class...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in Gradle:

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }
}
```

And perform a full clean and rebuild of all the project.